# LAS catalog not loading - Error in sp::SpatialPolygons

Tags: r, lidar, sp, lidr

I am getting this error that I have never received before. I have tried loading data in the catalog format with multiple LiDAR files including the `Megaplot.laz` data built into the `lidR` package.

Loading the data as a LAS file works normally:

```
> LASfile <- system.file("extdata", "Megaplot.laz", package="lidR")
> las = lidR::readLAS(LASfile)
```

Then when I try to load it as a LAS catalog I am getting this error:

```
> ctg <- readLAScatalog(LASfile)
Error in sp::SpatialPolygons(pgeom, proj4string = crs) : 
  is(proj4string, "CRS") is not TRUE

> ctg = lidR::catalog(LASfile)
Error in sp::SpatialPolygons(pgeom, proj4string = crs) : 
  is(proj4string, "CRS") is not TRUE
```

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already asked here: [Problem using lidR functions on Mac](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/414358/problem-using-lidr-functions-on-mac)

See this extensive discussion on lidR bug tracker: https://github.com/Jean-Romain/lidR/issues/485#issuecomment-944397838.

The conclusion was that CRAN binaries were temporarily corrupted. A new version has been released to trigger a new build. It was supposed to be fixed according to feedbacks. If not please report a bug.

**Edit:** Several people reported the issue. Because it is not reproducible systematically it took time to identify the issue. I released a fix on nov 13 2021. But it seems that reinstalling R does the trick because it is not a problem from lidR